# I need write validDate() function in java

Tags: java, string

I need a function to check a date with boolean. I have a String variable that stored one date. I stored date format is that "yyyy/mm/dd". I need to check if this variable is a valid date. If the date format is true then the function needs to return true in java. But I need something. I shouldn't use to convert string to integer. I have wrote something.

```
public boolean trueDate(String date){
    String[] temp;
    temp = date.split("/");
    String year = temp[0];
    String mounth = temp[1];
    String day = temp[2];

}
```

What should i do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public boolean trueDate(String date){
  String nums = "0123456789";
  String[] temp;
  temp = date.split("/");
  String year = temp[0];
  String month = temp[1];
  String day = temp[2];

  bool isValid = true;
  for(int i = 0; i < year.length(); i++)
  {
    if(nums.indexOf(year.charAt(i)) == -1)
    {
      isValid = false;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < month.length(); i++)
  {
    if(nums.indexOf(month.charAt(i)) == -1)
    {
      isValid = false;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < day.length(); i++)
  {
    if(nums.indexOf(day.charAt(i)) == -1)
    {
      isValid = false;
    }
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

Comment: That will throw an exception if the input string doesn't contain two slashes, it won't detect *more* than two slashes, and it will accept "9999/9999/9999" as a valid date.

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in reinventing the wheel here.

Either use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter` from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). Specify the appropriate format, and then try to parse it - if it doesn't throw an exception, it's valid.

If this is really just for homework then you *should* parse the strings as integers - how else are you going to do things like handling leap years etc?

You could use a regular expression to perform a cursory validation, but for "deep" validation you'd be much better off parsing the strings - or preferably using an existing library, as mentioned before.

Comment: Man i shouldnt use that.i need write my own function can i do this with chartat or etc. ???

Comment: @KaanAlvésKılıç: *Why* do you need to write your own method? *Why* don't you want to convert the strings into integers?

Comment: because of my lecturer wanted that and i trying to learn how can i do?

Comment: @KaanAlvésKılıç: It would help if a) you'd said this was homework to start with, b) you gave us the *exact* requirements, c) you told us where exactly you were stuck. No-one's going to do your assignment for you, but we can help you do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateFormat.parse](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).  If it throws a `ParseException` you know it's not a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SimpleDateFormat.  See http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14886-date-validation-using-simpledateformat/.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat is the built-in Java way to do what you're looking for. It's tried and true. Many sites with examples - here's one: http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/